# Global variable not being updated outside the global script

Tags: godot, godot4

Yes the ball is entering (and leaving) the area2D when i start the game

Yes `global.gd` is a autoloaded script

In global i have a big area2d that detect if a body have entered.
`var chase_ball` inside the global are being updated but in the `Global.chase_ball` its always false (the default value)

Originally the area2D was inside the enemy node but i wanna the area2D to be fixed in the main scene, not moving together with the enemy

global.gd:

```
extends Node2D

var chase_ball = false

func _process(delta):
        print(chase_ball)

func _on_ball_detector_body_entered(body):
    chase_ball = true

func _on_ball_detector_body_exited(body):
    chase_ball = false
```

output:

```
true
false
true
false
(same loop as above)
```

enemy.gd:

```
func _process(delta):
    print(Global.chase_ball)
```

output:

```
false
false
false
false
(same loop as above)
```

The expeted result is to `Global.chase_ball` update acordly to the `func _on_ball_detector_body_entered/exited(body):`

Comment: Are you talking about `global.gd` being an autoloaded script?

Comment: @Theraot  thanks for remember me (forget to add this in question).
But yes is a autoloaded script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are autoloading `global.gd`, then the Editor is not connecting the methods to the signals.

Yes, you have methods that match the signals, and you probably created them by connecting them... But the connection is not part of the script. Instead it is saved alongside the `Node` (i.e. it saved in a scene).

So when you autoload said script, Godot will create a new Node for it, and it does not have the connections.

---

Now, you say you want the `Area2D` - which would be emitting the signals - to be on your main scnee. So the path of least resistance would be to:

- Have a script on the `Area2D` itself.

  ```
  extends Area2D
  ```
- Connect the signals of the `Area2D` to itself using the editor, so there are methods for them in this new script.

  ```
  extends Area2D

  func _on_body_entered(body: Node2D)  -> void:
      pass

  func _on_body_exited(body: Node2D) -> void:
      pass
  ```
- And from those mehtod call the global.

  ```
  extends Area2D

  func _on_body_entered(body: Node2D)  -> void:
      Global._on_ball_detector_body_entered(body)

  func _on_body_exited(body: Node2D) -> void:
      Global._on_ball_detector_body_exited(body)
  ```

  Of course, at that point, you do not need to have those methods in `global.gd`, you can remove them and access `chase_ball` directly:

  ```
  extends Area2D

  func _on_body_entered(body: Node2D)  -> void:
      Global.chase_ball = true

  func _on_body_exited(body: Node2D) -> void:
      Global.chase_ball = false
  ```

Comment: Worked like a charm.
I just dont get why dont work the way  it was (i understood your explication).
When i ```print(chase_ball)``` inside the global its works fine.

Comment: @Willien At some point you had it in some scene where the `Area2D` was connected to it, and then either: 1. Removed it from there (so of course it wasn't connected anymore) and added it to autoloads (where it is not connected). or 2. You added it as an autoload without removing it, which resulted in a second instance, the old one is still connected but the one you access from the autoloads isn't. - I'll also point out that there are other ways nodes can communicate. For example, if you use an `static var`, all instances would share it.

Comment: oooh geit (i think) tks mate.